# Substring by line number

Tags: java, string

Is there a way to substring by the string line?

Someting like: String.substring(line_num);

Or we hava to do it manually by calculating the indexes?

Comment: What do you mean "string line"? As is the line of the string, i.e. denoted by the `\n` character?

Comment: you can use ``String.split("\n")[line_num];``

Comment: What do you mean by string line? Can you show how your strings look like

Comment: @Vulcan yes, for example line 3 will give the text from line 3 until the end

Comment: @MichaelA From line 3 and everything following it, including lines 4, 5, and so forth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can, however, split the string by `\n` and then get the required line:

```
String s = "First line\nSecond line\nThird line\nFourth line";
String[] lines = s.split("\n", -1);
System.out.println(lines[2]); // Third line
```

If you don't know what the line separator of your platform is, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Or if you want to get a *range* of lines, use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String s = "First line\nSecond line\nThird line\nFourth line";
String[] lines = s.split("\n", -1);
String[] lines2To4 = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 1, 4);
```

Comment: @Mankarse There is nothing wrong with the technique. The problem is very, very minor: just use `split("\n", -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String substringLine(String text, int lineNumber){
    String[] textLines = text.split("[\r\n]+");
    return textLines.length < lineNumber ? textLines[lineNumber] : null;
}
```

This is simple method which do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a built-in way to do it, but you can write a simple and fast program that finds you the right line without unnecessary allocations:

```
public static String substringByLine(String s, int n) {
    int pos = -1, start;
    do {
        pos = s.indexOf('\n', start = pos+1);
        if (pos < 0) {
            pos = s.length();
            break;
        }
    } while (n-- > 0);
    return n <= 0 ? s.substring(start, pos) : null;
}
```

Here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/aJNgC).